# Child component's props not updating when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using drag and drop to instantiate react classes, but for some reason the state from the parent component is not being passed to the child. The child isn't even being rerendered, tried shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps.

Parents relevant code:

```
dragEnd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let me = this;

    let el = (
        <Pie key={ Date.now() * Math.random() } yAxisData={ me.state.yAxisData } legendData={ me.state.legendData } />
    )

    this.setState({
        cells: this.state.cells.concat(el),
    });
}
```

So, on drop,  is created, and then render looks like:

```
render() {
    <div className = { "insights-data" } onDrop={ this.dragEnd } onDragOver={ this.preventDefault }>
        { this.state.cells }
    </div>
}
```

All this works fine, but now when I change the data passed to this.state.yAxisData and/or this.state.legendData, it's not calling render on the child component.

Here's the child components render:

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="insights-cell">
            <ReactECharts
                option={ this.create() }
                style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: "100%" }}
                theme="chalk"
                notMerge={ true }
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any ideas? I thought maybe there was a binding issue, but that doesn't seem to be it, as I'm using me = this. It's not even re-rendering the child component.

Comment: Hmm, if you make an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Oh man, that's a lot of work to recreate what I'm doing in a fiddle. I may have to do that, but trying to avoid for the moment. Let me see if I can just make a quick example and recreate my issue.

Comment: Sure, a quick example is all that's needed.

Comment: @stevelacerda7 In `dragEnd` function, you are already creating the array of element with predefined props. You should create a new element on every render.

Comment: But, it should reference the state object right, why would I have to recreate them if they're just referencing the state object? I'm not overwriting my state object anywhere.

Comment: @Colin - okay, I did something similar. Maybe you can explain to me why the original value stays the same. If you click on the green box, you'll get the time, then click it again, you'll get the original time, plus a new time. Why does the original time stay the same. It's referencing this.state object, so it seems that the reference is referencing an old object...why?

Comment: @PrakashSharma is right, keeping components in state in not what you should be doing. Components themselves are not state. His answer below is what you should be doing. Don't worry about the performance of it, React will handle it efficiently.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so now how do I create a new element on each render if I don't know what that element is going to be? So, they drag some element over, which could be a pie chart, line chart, or whatever. What should I store then and then how will I render that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already creating the element in `dragEnd` function by passing props to it and storing them to an array. Therefore the array `this.state.cells` contain the array of already declared elements. Therefore it cannot update on state change. You should render a new array of element on every render.

Just push some necessary detail of dragged element in `this.state.cells` and then iterate through this array on every render.

```
dragEnd(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let el = draggedElementType

    this.setState({
        cells: this.state.cells.concat(el),
    });
}
```

And in render, iterate through this array and return the desired element.

```
render() {
    <div className = { "insights-data" } onDrop={ this.dragEnd } onDragOver={ this.preventDefault }>
        { this.state.cells.map((cell, index) => {
           if (cell === "pie") {
           return (<Pie key={index} yAxisData={ me.state.yAxisData } legendData={ me.state.legendData } />);
           }
           else if (){...
        )}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: okay, thanks, but I can't use <Pie .../> because I don't know if that's what it is, it can't be hard-code because it can be Pie or Line or something else. Do I have to do an if/else conditional, and just store "pie" and if id==="pie" then use <Pie ... />

Comment: If you keep the key consistent, then react can optimize this better. I would use `let el = "pushed element " + Date.now() * Math.random();` - and when mapping like this: `cells.map(el => <Pie key={el} ... />)`

Comment: @stevelacerda7 You need to store that value in `this.state.cells` array (i.e. wheather it was pie or line etc).

Comment: Okay, so I can't actually store the element, but store something so that I know what element I need to create. Makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wouldn't generate random keys every render. Your performance goes away. Make sure to generate the key once in the `dragEnd` method.

Comment: @RyanWheale You are right. @stevelacerda7 Please read about `keys`. Random keys are not performance friendly.